# Is 'plate between studs' SNOT supported by one of the LEGO building software?

Tags: software, snot, cad

Do any of the multiple LEGO building software supports 'plate between studs' SNOT assembly?

[image]

Comment: I presume it must be considering it has been rendered on [this](http://swooshable.com/snot/snot/plates-between-studs/) page.

Comment: @Ambo100 I'm looking for a virtual building software (like LEGO Digital Designer or LDraw). Your link (even though I didn't know it and it's really cool) seam to be a SNOT technique listing

Comment: That's right. I was hoping to find more information on what software was used. All I know for now is that it IS possible.

Comment: ...or it's Photoshopable :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To build your example in MLCad (LDraw), I needed to switch to "Grid Fine" to move the element into the right alignment:

[image: 1x2 between the studs of 2x3 and 2x2 from MLCad]
[image: Enable "Fine" grid snap setting]

A couple of techniques to note when doing this when you finish with the SNOT modeling:

1. Set the grid back to coarse so that subsequent pieces are back on the grid.
2. Select a non-SNOT element (in this case the 2x3 or 2x2 plate) before placing the next element - grid alignment and rotation are inherited from the last selected piece, so this gets you back to "normal".

See also Joubarc's renderings for my [Heroica Graveyard question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/636/56), again from LDraw by the looks of things, with the elements are added within the clips or between grills in the radiators:

[image: Heroica Graveyard with grille fence]
[image: Heroica Graveyard with lattice fence]

Comment: Yes, I did use BrickSmith instead of MLcad, but the same principle of using a fine grid applies. Since neither checks for validity, you can do pretty much whatever you want (including impossible things).

Comment: I'll have to check that out - it looks like a better default renderer. For simple things like this I can't be fussed opening in LeoCad, exporting to .3ds, and then setting up a scene in 3dsMax to render shineys ;)

Comment: Hmm, scrub that, it's Mac based ;)

Comment: Actually, BrickSmith is a LDraw editor only. I did the rendering with [LDview](http://ldview.sourceforge.net/) which appears to have a windows version too.

Comment: Yep, I've played around with LDView - most of my models on here are just screen grabs straight from MLCad.